# Sound Problem in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: audio

I have a desktop computer(HP Intel Core 2 Duo). After installing Ubuntu 9.10, I have no sound.

Comment: check grub.conf file for the latest kernel version

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, make sure you have set the volume higher than 0%.

If you upgraded Ubuntu and it worked on 9.04 but not anymore in 9.10 check that you are booting the right kernel: vmlinuz-2.6.31-(something) and not the one from previous version vmlinuz-2.6.28-(something).

Second step is to kick the pulseaudio dæmon: `killall pulseaudio`. Pulseaudio will restart itself and audio *should* be fixed after that. At least [until the next reboot](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/384015).

Comment: Also, check cables! ;)